# Difference between e.printStackTrace and System.out.println(e)

Tags: java, exception

Probably a newbie question, but everyone seems to use `e.printStackTrace()`, but I have always used `System.out.println(e)` when exception handling. What is the difference and why is `e.printStackTrace()` preferable?

Comment: Try them and you will see what the difference is. You can read the code for printStackTrace() as well.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The output stream used is not the same as pointed out by @Brian, but the level of detail is not the same either - you can try with the simple test below. Output:

With `println`: you only know what exception has been thrown

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented

With `printStackTrace`: you also know what caused it *(line numbers + call stack)*

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
>       at javaapplication27.Test1.test(Test1.java:27)
>       at javaapplication27.Test1.main(Test1.java:19)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        test();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void test() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use `System.out.println`, then you're dumping your errors to the `stdout`, not `stderr`.

It's traditional to dump errors to standard error, so you can filter normal successful output from the error output. It's a common practise for command-line utilities and consequently a good idea to follow.

e.g.

```
myCommand 2> /tmp/errors > /tmp/results
```

will write errors to one log, and the results to another. Depending on your shell/invoking process etc. you can combine this info, throw errors away, react if any errors are thrown etc. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for more info.

Using `printStackTrace()` is a good idea since you're dumping out where the exception took place. This is often invaluable for tracking errors that are unexpected since it'll give you a direct (if verbose) pointer to where exactly you ran into an error.

Comment: @imulsion in unixes --perhaps in Wondows as well, I don't know-- you can redirect standard output and error messages separately like this `yourProgram > ~/fileThatContainsStandardOutput.txt 2> ~/fileThatContainsErrors.txt`

Comment: Between what and what ? stdout and stderr ? I've tried to illustrate above

Comment: In Eclipse, stdout appears in the console in black, while stderr appears in red. More generally, they are just two output streams which you can treat however you like.

Answer (score 8):

`System.out.println(e)` is equivalent to `System.out.println(e.toString())`: `System.out` is a PrintStream, `PrintStream.println(Object o)` calls `PrintStream.println(o.toString())`.

`e.toString()` returns the name of the class, and the exception's getLocalizedMessage().

`e.printStackTrace()` writes that information to System.err (not System.out) and *also* a stack trace, that is, the chain of methods that led to the exception. This is useful information.

I've often thought it would be nice if there was a method that returns a String containing the info that's output by `e.printStackTrace()`. Since there isn't you have to use `e.getStackTrace()` and write your own routine to output the resulting array of StackTraceElements.

Comment: There is `e.getStackTrace()` that returns an array of objects. Also, _printStackTrace_ accepts a `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` parameter - so you could pass it a StringWriter object or any other streamer to extract the data.

Comment: OutputStream.println is confusing as OutputStream doesn't have any methods.Its only defined in PrintStream.

Comment: So `System.err.println(e);`  __==__  `e.getStackTrace()` ?

Comment: @roottraveller. `System.err.println(e);` has a void return and prints the exception's `toString()` to stderr. There's no stack trace in that output. `e.getStackTrace()` returns an array of `StackTraceElement`. This is all in the JavaDoc and easy to try for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Since the output of `e.printStackTrace();` is `System.err` and usually I output my app log to a file, I recommend you to use both `System.err` and `System.out` to output errors.

```
public static void log(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // This goes to System.err
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

This way you can see the errors in the log file (in case you have one) and in the console.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that it's possible to redirect the stack trace to the console with `System.out` as input argument.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(e)` will not give you your stack trace, just the error message and exception type, as well as being printed to the standard output as opposed to error output.

Answer (score 0):

> **Bellow Program show the difference details**
>
> **System.out.println(e); :-**   only showing the exception.
>   e.g.java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>     **e.printStackTrace(); :-**     showing the details of exception and where
>   to cause exception in program with line number  e.g.
>   java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero at
>   test.Test.main(Test.java:7)

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println(12 / 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `System.out.println(e)` you only get on to know what exception is thrown but with `e.printStackTrace()` you get information about what exception is thrown and what caused it.