# Query, java on database

Tags: java, sql

I am having some issues with querying/comparing results on database.

I have prepared a Java program(class `Filename`) to parse the filenames and with those filenames, then I am doing query on database to see if there are entries in database with those filenames already or not. If there is, I can then input some values. If not, I have to log it as failed.

1. How do I do query on all filenames not just specific ones by calling
   on output that I made from another Java file(output already from
   another Java program)? My implementation seems wrong.
2. What can I do so that when there is a match, I can input data
   values? If not, mark it as failed?

---

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;

    try {
        conn = DBConnect.getTime().dbOracleConnect();
        String sql= "select * from PO_Parent_List"
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        datasets = Class.Filename(output);
        pst.setString(1, datasets);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("...Statements...")

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `e.printStackTrace()` not `System.out.println(e)`. See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095378/difference-between-e-printstacktrace-and-system-out-printlne)

Comment: If you want to search for columnwise then you will have to build the quierie accordingly. Something like `select * from table1 where col1 like '%filename1%' OR col1 like '%filename2%'..` **OR** if you have specific name then you can also use `IN` clause. (HINT:::use Stringbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting them from a directory on your system, you need to do something like to get a list of the files:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");

File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Then loop through the filenames and build a query like

```
SELECT * FROM PO_Parent_List WHERE file_name IN (<filename>, <filename>, etc...);
```

And that will return you all the matching filenames.

For question 2, you can do a `UPDATE PO_Parent_List`  for each match while you're traversing your resultSet.

Comment: The thing is filename has to be parsed to specific name. In this case, how do I use the output from the other java file that I made? Also, there are over 400 files so I can't just list them...